# Focus on selected date after form submit in onSelect function

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker, onselect

I've got a few problems with query ui datepicker inline.
Here is html:

```
<form id="form" method="post">
..
'<div class="calendar"></div>'
</form>
```

and this is part of .js:

```
var regionalIs = $.datepicker.regional[ "ru" ];
 $( '.calendar' ).datepicker(
    {
        dateFormat: 'dd.mm.yy',
        numberOfMonths: 3,
        onSelect: function (dateText, inst) {
            $("#form").append('<input type="hidden" name="date" value="'+ dateText +'">');
            $("#form").submit();
        },

    });
$( '.calendar' ).datepicker( regionalIs ).datepicker('refresh');
```

I need the selected date to be focused and highlighted after form submit. Now datepicker reloads and current date is focused and highlighted. Can anyone help, please?

Comment: you are using form submit(),it reloads the whole page use ajax instead

Comment: ok, I know that the page reloads, but for example I can put on page some span like <span id="sdate" style="display:none;">20.08.2013</span> with the selected date and take it in onSelect function from this span. How can i make it focused   then ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Sample working **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sarathsprakash/x8F2G/1/)**

Form submit reloads the page completely , so the datetimepicker also get refreshed after form submit, Using ajax will make it works

Try  this

```
$( '.calendar' ).datepicker(
    {
        dateFormat: 'dd.mm.yy',
        numberOfMonths: 3,
        onSelect: function (dateText, inst) {
            $("#form").append('<input type="hidden" name="date" value="'+ dateText +'">');
            $.ajax({
                    url:"  ",          // give your url
                    data: $("#form").serialize(),
                    success: function()  
                  {
                    alert("success");
                   }
           });
        },

    });
```

Hope this helps, Thank you

Comment: Thanks, this is nice, but not really what I needed. The problem is solved with using option 'defaultDate' and selected date value in it.